# Command output in vi editor

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I open a text file using vi editor in linux and want to insert date command output without exiting vi editor. What is the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

:r !date

or to add one week to the current date:

:r !date -d “today 1 week”

Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim